# Триггер аудита SQLite

Tags: sqlite, триггеры-sql

Создаю триггер аудита в SQLite. Необходимо, чтобы при любом UPDATE триггер задал NEW.change_date этой же таблицы в значение текущей даты. Простое выражение NEW.change_date = ... не пускает

```
CREATE TRIGGER DRCT_AUDIT
UPDATE ON DIRECTORIES
BEGIN
    NEW.change_date = strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;
```

Такой синтаксис недопустим в SQLite? Есть ли какая-нибудь замена?

Получилось только так, но выглядит, по-моему, не очень:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DRCT_AUDIT
     UPDATE OF <здесь исключен change_date>
            ON DIRECTORIES
BEGIN
    UPDATE directories
       SET change_date = strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
     WHERE drct_id = NEW.drct_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш второй вариант ближе к правде.  Вот как можно ещё:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS
 AFTER UPDATE
    ON directories
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE directories
     SET change_date = STRFTIME('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   WHERE drct_id = NEW.drct_id
  ;
END
;
```

Comment: Именно так нельзя, только UPDATE OF <...>, иначе рекурсия. Просто смутило, что нельзя в теле триггера менять вставляемые значения. До этого только с Oracle имел дело - он так даёт делать.

Comment: @h8d  У меня всё работает без рекурсии.

Comment: Странно. SQLite Studio ругается: [17:59:10] An error occurred while committing the data: too many levels of trigger recursion. Это когда непосредственно update делаю уже.

Comment: Вы воспроизвели мой триггер точно?  Может, дело в версиях?  У меня `3.31.1`.  Если что, вот документация: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html.

Comment: Версия 3.24 пишет